# Official, Up-to-date List of Supported Operating Systems (Windows, MacOs, Linux, etc.)

Tags: operating-systems

I am trying to find out-of-support operating systems in my environment via logs. I can query log data to get installed OS, but I need to compare that to what is currently supported. Ideally I would have this auto-update and build a dashboard that can be run on demand, but Googling has not helped much and I have only started with Windows!

**Where can I find a regularly updated list of supported Operating systems? (I'll take any known lists, the more comprehensive, consumable, and updated the better)**
Preferably in a consumable manner.

Logs for Windows (that I will be comparing said list to) look like this:

```
Type=OperatingSystem
OS="Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise"
Architecture="64-bit"
Version="10.0.19043"
BuildNumber="19043"
BuildType="Multiprocessor Free"
ServicePack=
SerialNumber="00XXX-XXXXX-00003-XXXXX"
ComputerName="<name>"
<...>
SystemDirectory="C:\WINDOWS\system32"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an entirely different approach to solving this: use a scanning service such as Qualys or Tenable/Nessus to determine you risk level.

Tenable has a list of Plugins that detect OS, including out of support OSs.
https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nnm/families/Operating%20System%20Detection

Get a scanner and scan your environment. Let someone else do all that work .

Answer (score 0):

I found the following *start* for a list:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/supported-versions-windows-client

This is for Windows, and appears to be updated as needed by Microsoft. Not terribly consumable, but is scrape-able.

I will update this answer as I discover more.